# Does the Gang of Six immigration plan expand Chain Migration and Visa Lotteries?

Tags: united-states, politics, immigration

President Trump just tweeted [this](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/951785587765280768):

> The so-called bipartisan DACA deal presented yesterday to myself and a group of Republican Senators and Congressmen was a big step backwards. Wall was not properly funded, **Chain & Lottery were made worse** and USA would be forced to take large numbers of people from high crime countries which are doing badly. I want a merit based system of immigration and people who will help take our country to the next level. I want safety and security for our people. I want to stop the massive inflow of drugs. I want to fund our military, not do a Dem defund.

I'm interested in the part in bold.  Obviously "made worse" is subjective.  But President Trump wants to do away with the chain migration and the Diversity Visa Lottery Program.  So is it true that the Gang of Six immigration plan expands those two things, thereby going in the opposite of President Trump's preferred direction?

Comment: I don't think any concrete details have been worked out or announced. A statement from the "Gang of Six" said they only "have reached an agreement in principle" and are trying to find congressional support. https://www.usnews.com/news/politics/articles/2018-01-11/senators-say-daca-border-security-deal-reached-in-principle

Comment: If I expanded on the above would you accept it as an answer?

Comment: [Gang of six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Six)?? This question (or the Wikipedia article) needs additional explanation. We're not all from the US here.